# Problema com valores randômicos

Tags: c, funções, random

Boa noite, galera.

Estou resolvendo um exercício onde devo, a cada execução, gerar um número randômico e depois transformá-lo em letra.

Para isso fiz uma função. Está quase tudo certo, o número é gerado e é transformado em letra. Porém, cada vez que executo o programa, ele sempre dá a mesma sequência de números/caracteres. Ou seja, não está randômico.

O código da função é:

```c
int inserir_fila(int x)
{
char ch;
if (fim_fila<=MAX)
    {
        x= rand()% 26;
        ch= x + 'A';
        fim_fila++;
        fila[fim_fila]=ch;
    }
     else
      {
        printf("Fila Cheia!\n");
      }
 return(x);
}
```

Se precisar, posto o código inteiro.

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `rand()` vai buscar um número a uma lista fixa de números aleatórios.

Se não escolheres uma lista específica, o C usa a lista #1.

Para escolheres uma lista específica usa `srand()` passando o número da lista que vais usar.

```c
srand(1);          // usa lista #1
srand(42);         // usa lista #42
srand(1234567);    // usa lista #1,234,567
srand(time(NULL)); // usa lista #(numero de segundos desde 1970-01-01)
```

Nota que deves apenas especificar a lista a usar uma única vez em cada execução do teu programa. Principalmente não ponhas o `srand()` dentro dum ciclo. O uso básico, é colocar o `srand(time(NULL))` no princípio da função `main` e a partir daí, usar sempre e só `rand()` as vezes necessárias para ir percorrendo a lista de números pseudo-aleatórios.

O teu programa ficaria então:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL)); // especificar lista de numeros aleatorios
    // ...
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        inserir_fila(k);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Agora não está mais repetindo, porém, está apresentando caracteres que eu não posso apresentar, como caracteres especiais e letras minúsculas.
PS. Não estou usando void

Answer (score 0):

Ve os meus comentarios abaixo. Os comentarios dizem respeito as linhas assinaladas

```
int inserir_fila(int x)      // [1]
{
char ch;
if (fim_fila<=MAX)
    {
        x= rand()% 26;
        ch= x + 'A';
        fim_fila++;          // [2]
        fila[fim_fila]=ch;   // [3]
    }
     else
      {
        printf("Fila Cheia!\n");
      }
 return(x);                  // [4]
}
```

[1] Para que serve o parametro `x`? Ele nao e usado na funcao!

[2] e [3] *Assumindo que `fila` e `fim_fila` sao variaveis globais correctamente definidas* Nunca vais escrever no primeiro elemento de `fila`. `fila` comeca com `fila[0]`, mas o valor de `fim_fila` passa a `1` antes da atribuicao.

[4] Qual a razao de devolveres o ultimo caracter aleatorio gerado?

[*] E ainda: o array `fila` precisa de um terminador para ser uma string. A ultima letra aleatoria deve ser seguida por `'\0'`.

Habitua-te a **NAO USAR** variaveis globais.